# ASP.NET - The real need of CrosSite Scripting checking for my simple W3 School-like Try It Yourself

Tags: html, asp.net, xss

I'm building a web site with ASP.NET and I would like to offer to its user the chance to test their html5/css/javascript code.

In order to reach this aim I've realized a Try It Yourself editor similar to that of W3School.

This editor submit via POST the HTML code from a text area on current page to a TryIt.aspx page visualized as an iframe next to the text area.

The code behind the TryIt.aspx is following

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RunScriptCode();            
    }

    private void RunScriptCode()
    {
        string resultValue;

        try
        {
            HttpContext c = HttpContext.Current;
            NameValueCollection f = c.Request.Form;
            resultValue = f["textareacodeinput"];
            Response.Headers.Add("X-XSS-Protection", "0");
            if (resultValue != null)
            {
                Response.Write(resultValue);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

So the `resultValue` retrieve the HTML code inside the input text area posted from the current page; this code is then written as HTML on TryIt.aspx trhough `Response.Write(resultValue)`.

I added the header `Response.Headers.Add("X-XSS-Protection", "0");` to disable the cross-site scripting filter on Chrome.

Now, because no db is involved in the this simple Try It Yourself code editor, I've thought to not to implement any security against XSS

Anyway I wonder if my thought id correct or of my way to build is prone to some XSS attack that can exploit my website or the ASP.NET Server publishing my site.

Can anyone help me with some suggestions?

Many many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think my thought is correct.

After some google searches I downolad form [OWASP Zed Attack Proxy](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/ZAP) a web site vulnerability scanner and attacked with it my web site to verify its security.

The result of the scan didn't revealed any serious burden.

Thank you very much.